# Compare date in lightning web component

Tags: apex, lightning-web-components, date, event

I want to compare my two dates, start date with end date, if start date >= end date so I can save if not I can't save, the problem I have is that in the console I get only the value of the end date and the start date is undefined , so always my condition goes to the else .
How can I correct this?

==> JS

```
CompareDate(event){
        
        if (this.EndDate >= this.StartDate) {
            console.log('EndDate  > StartDate');
            console.log(' date fin est '+this.EndDate );
            console.log('date début'+this.StartDate);
            this.EndDate = event.target.value;
            this.Submit = true;
           
           
        }

        else {
            console.log('EndDate< StartDate');
            console.log('valeur date'+this.EndDate);
            console.log('date début'+this.StartDate);
            this.EndDate= event.target.value;
            this.Submit = false;
           


        }

    }
```

==> HTML

```
 <td>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="Start_Date__c" required onchange={CompareDate}   value={StartDate}>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                      </td>
<td>
                        <lightning-input-field field-name="EndDate__c" required  onchange={CompareDate} value={EndDate}>
                        </lightning-input-field>
                      </td>
```

Comment: @sfdcfox I Used this code in the case : `case 'Start_Date__c': `  to get just to get the Today Date not also the Date Time   but I get the correct forma of Date but my condition go automatically to the Case number 2 and give me that the start date is undefined               
 `let rightNow = new Date();
  rightNow.setMinutes(
  new Date().getMinutes() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset()
                );
   this.startDate = rightNow.toISOString().slice(0,10);
   console.log(startDate); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Data bindings are one-way in LWC, so you have to set the value in the variables first:

```
if(event.target.fieldName === 'Start_Date__c') {
  this.StartDate = event.target.value;
} else if(event.target.fieldName === 'End_Date__c') {
  this.EndDate = event.target.value;
}
this.Submit = this.StartDate && this.EndDate && this.StartDate < this.EndDate;
```

---

I wrote a demo app that works in my org.

```
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
    
export default class StartEndDemo extends LightningElement {
    startDate = new Date().toISOString();
    endDate;
    canSubmit;
    get cannotSubmit() {
        return !this.submit;
    }
    handleChange(event) {
        switch( event.target.fieldName) {
            case 'Start_Date__c': {
                this.startDate = event.target.value;
                break;
            }
            case 'End_Date__c': {
                this.endDate = event.target.value;
            }
        }
        this.submit = this.startDate && this.endDate && this.startDate < this.endDate;
    }
}
```

---

```
<template>
    <lightning-record-edit-form object-api-name="Account">
        <lightning-input-field field-name="Start_Date__c" onchange={handleChange} value={startDate}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-input-field field-name="End_Date__c" onchange={handleChange} value={endDate}></lightning-input-field>
        <lightning-button type="submit" label="Save" disabled={cannotSubmit}></lightning-button>
    </lightning-record-edit-form>
    Start: {startDate}<br/>
    End: {endDate}
</template>
```

Comment: I get an error with this code `This page contains an error. Try updating it. To start, would you like to give us some information? (we designate this error with the ID: -455474642) `

Comment: @salesforcedev Hmm, I made a demo in my org, it works correctly. Please review my code and compare it to your own.

Comment: thank you for your help , Yes now it works, the problem I had and I just discovered is that the start date is automatically fed by today's date, so if I don't click it considers it as indefinite , does this have a solution?

Comment: @salesforcedev Yes, you can initialize the value to whatever you desire in a number of ways. Let me write something up.

Comment: Yes , If you can help I will be Grateful

Comment: @salesforcedev I've already edited in an example.

Comment: `@sfdcfox I Used this code in the case : case 'Start_Date__c':  to get just to get the Today Date not also the Date Time but I get the correct forma of Date but my condition go automatically to the Case number 2 and give me that the start date is undefined let rightNow = new Date();   rightNow.setMinutes(   new Date().getMinutes() - new Date().getTimezoneOffset()                 );    this.startDate = rightNow.toISOString().slice(0,10);    console.log(startDate);

Comment: @salesforcedev You can use `new Date().toISOString().substring(0, 10)` if you really need to.

Comment: Thank you very much, now it works for me, one last question please, for my case, I am using submit in two methods, but now the condition that exists in the other method when it is false I can still save ( it now only takes the case of the date to register or not, do you have any proposals) .

Comment: The other method : `Details(event) {
        if (event.target.value == 'Closed') {
            let desc = this.template.querySelector('[data-id="description"]').value;
            this.disableButton2 = true;
            this.Submit = false;  
        } else {
            this.info = event.target.value;
            this.disableButton2 = false;
            this.required = true;
            this.Submit = true;
        }
    }`

Comment: @salesforcedev I suggest asking as a new question so we can see all the related code. We'll need both your current markup and the functions in question, as well as any related data (e.g. variables/properties that are relevant). We'll be happy to help you out.

Comment: actually this is not a new question as it is related to the first treatment done,
The Submit method can be true or false, and in this second method I just shared, it used to work but now the submit only takes into consideration the date condition.

Comment: I posted the problem as a new question : https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/374059/method-called-problem